# Pascal's Triangle + Fibonacci Numbers

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I draw this picture in LaTeX, with those skew lines? Any hints?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, You're absolutely right, actually it's not hard for me to create the triangle, the main problem I had was the skew line. Now thanks to you guys I learned it. I'll be appreciate if someone introduce some good sources to learn these kind of stuffs.

Comment: I accept the (Maarten Dhondt)'s answer because of it's short and clever use of (tikz), but I learned other things from other answers too. I'm new at these things so there is a lot to learn.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

EDIT: changed `\ifthenelse` to `\ifnum` as suggested by percusse and Heiko.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \n in {0,...,6} {
            \foreach \k in {0,...,\n} {
                \node (\n\k) at (\k,-\n) {${\n \choose \k}$};
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\x}{(\n+1)/2}
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\y}{\n/2}
                \ifnum\k=0 \draw (\n\k.south west) -- (\x\y.north east);\fi
            }
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

EDIT 2: Eliminated if statement as suggested by Misch:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \n in {0,...,6} {
            \foreach \k in {0,...,\n} {
                \node (\n\k) at (\k,-\n) {${\n \choose \k}$};
            }
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\x}{(\n+1)/2}
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\y}{\n/2}
            \draw (\n0.south west) -- (\x\y.north east);
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is better than my solution, of course;-) I should really learn `tikz` (+1)

Comment: +1 You beat me to it! :P I was this close earlier but then I had to get lunch. :P

Comment: You can remove the package with `\ifnum\k=0\draw (\n\k.south west) -- (\x\y.north east);\fi`

Comment: I would add a space after the zero: `\ifnum\k=0 \draw`. Otherwise TeX unnecessarily expands `\draw` in the search for digits.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek My bad. Too fast typing. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: You don't even need the if construct. You can just move the last three lines of the inner loop out of the inner loop, and replace `\n\k` with `\n0`

Comment: True. Good catch! I made an edit.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't precisely what the OP requests, I think, but it's similar...

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cancel}


\begin{document}
\LARGE \boldmath
% horizontal loop
\foreach \x in {0,...,6} {%
% vertical loop

\foreach \y in {0,...,\x} {%
$\cancel{\binom{\x}{\y}}$
}

}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1, but I'm curious about why you're using `\boldmath`.

Comment: @HenriMenke: To exaggerate only ;-)

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cancel,mathtools,stackengine}
\stackMath
\def\CBN#1#2{%
  \cancel{\addstackgap[6pt]{\kern6pt\displaystyle\binom{#1}{#2}\kern6pt}}%
  }
\def\BN#1#2{%
  \addstackgap[6pt]{\kern6pt\displaystyle\binom{#1}{#2}\kern6pt}%
  }
\begin{document}
\[
\def\stackalignment{l}
\setstackgap{S}{-5.2pt}
\setstackEOL{\cr}
\Shortstack{
\CBN{0}{0}\cr
\CBN{1}{0}\CBN{1}{1}\cr
\CBN{2}{0}\CBN{2}{1}\CBN{2}{2}\cr
\CBN{3}{0}\CBN{3}{1}\CBN{3}{2}\CBN{3}{3}\cr
\CBN{4}{0}\CBN{4}{1}\CBN{4}{2}\BN{4}{3}\BN{4}{4}\cr
\CBN{5}{0}\CBN{5}{1}\BN{5}{2}\BN{5}{3}\BN{5}{4}\BN{5}{5}\cr
\CBN{6}{0}\BN{6}{1}\BN{6}{2}\BN{6}{3}\BN{6}{4}\BN{6}{5}\BN{6}{6}
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]